# In Bash, how can I parse multiple newline delimited JSON objects from a log file?

Tags: json, linux, bash, grep, xargs

I am parsing through a log file and get result lines (using grep) like the following:

```
2017-01-26 17:19:40 +0000 docker: {"source":"stdout","log":"I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.703988 #24]  INFO -- : {\"tags\":\"structured_log\",\"payload\":{\"results\":[{\"baserate\":\"-1\"}]},\"commit_stamp\":1485451180,\"resource\":\"google_price_result_metric\",\"object_id\":\"20170126171940700\"}","container_id":"6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e","container_name":"/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300"}
2017-01-26 17:19:40 +0000 docker: {"container_id":"6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e","container_name":"/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300","source":"stdout","log":"I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.704364 #24]  INFO -- : method=POST path=/prices.xml format=xml controller=TestController action=prices status=200 duration=1686.51 view=0.08 db=0.62"}
```

I then extract the JSON objects with the following command:

`... | grep -o -E "\{.*$"`

I know I can parse a single line with `python -mjson.tool` like so:

`... | grep -o -E "\{.*$" | tail -n1 | python -mjson.tool`

**But I want to parse *both* lines (or n lines).  How can I do this in bash?** 
(I think xargs is supposed to let me do this, but I am new to the tool and can't figure it out)

Comment: Why not just put it all in a python script?

Comment: If you want to parse JSON in a shell script, get the `jq` tool.

Comment: You saw this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: If you want to do this on an ongoing/streaming basis, it's something that's liable to be in the domain of [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) -- certainly, part of what it's built to do *well* (at-scale with good error handling).

Comment: That said, to be clear, you *could* do this with `jq` -- it's perfectly capable of taking raw text as input, extracting a substring and parsing that substring as JSON.

Comment: btw -- `xargs` is responsible for transforming stdin to *argument lists*. Since you don't want to pass your JSON as a command-line argument to `python -m json.tool`, it's not an appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) can be told to accept plain text as input, and attempt to parse an extracted subset as JSON. Consider the following example, tested with jq 1.5:

```
jq -R 'capture("docker: (?<json>[{].*[}])$") | .json? | select(.) | fromjson' <<'EOF'
2017-01-26 17:19:40 +0000 docker: {"source":"stdout","log":"I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.703988 #24]  INFO -- : {\"tags\":\"structured_log\",\"payload\":{\"results\":[{\"baserate\":\"-1\"}]},\"commit_stamp\":1485451180,\"resource\":\"google_price_result_metric\",\"object_id\":\"20170126171940700\"}","container_id":"6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e","container_name":"/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300"}
2017-01-26 17:19:40 +0000 docker: {"container_id":"6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e","container_name":"/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300","source":"stdout","log":"I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.704364 #24]  INFO -- : method=POST path=/prices.xml format=xml controller=TestController action=prices status=200 duration=1686.51 view=0.08 db=0.62"}
EOF
```

...properly yields:

```
{
  "source": "stdout",
  "log": "I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.703988 #24]  INFO -- : {\"tags\":\"structured_log\",\"payload\":{\"results\":[{\"baserate\":\"-1\"}]},\"commit_stamp\":1485451180,\"resource\":\"google_price_result_metric\",\"object_id\":\"20170126171940700\"}",
  "container_id": "6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e",
  "container_name": "/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300"
}
{
  "container_id": "6ecbf7f64e4c9557e9dd1efbc6666a3c6c53f9cd5c18414ed5633cad8c302e",
  "container_name": "/test-container-b49c8188c3ebe4b93300",
  "source": "stdout",
  "log": "I, [2017-01-26T17:19:40.704364 #24]  INFO -- : method=POST path=/prices.xml format=xml controller=TestController action=prices status=200 duration=1686.51 view=0.08 db=0.62"
}
```